# Symfony2 ,doctrine custom DQL function

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I've created a custom 'REPLACE' function in Doctrine.
But I have an error ,when I use it.

```php
$result->andWhere("replace(weight,X,C) <= :weight_from")
       ->setParameter('weight_from',$data['weight_from']);
```

**Replace function:**

```php
namespace Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions;

use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer;

/**
 * "REPLACE" "(" StringPrimary "," StringSecondary "," StringThird ")"
 *
 * 
 * @link    www.prohoney.com
 * @since   2.0
 * @author  Igor Aleksejev
 */
class ReplaceFunction extends FunctionNode {

    public $stringPrimary;
    public $stringSecondary;
    public $stringThird;

    /**
     * @override
     */
    public function getSql(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker $sqlWalker) {
        return $sqlWalker->getConnection()->getDatabasePlatform()->getReplaceExpression(
                        $this->stringPrimary, $this->stringSecondary, $this->stringThird
        );
    }

    /**
     * @override
     */
    public function parse(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser $parser) {
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER);
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS);
        $this->stringPrimary = $parser->StringPrimary();
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_COMMA);
        $this->stringSecondary = $parser->StringPrimary();
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_COMMA);
        $this->stringThird = $parser->StringPrimary();
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS);
    }

}
```

**AbstracPlatfrom.php contains:**

```php
/**
 * Returns the replace of a text field.
 *
 * @param string $column
 * @param string $x
 * @param string $y
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getReplaceExpression($column,$x,$y)
{
    return "REPLACE($column,'$x','$y')";
}
```

Error:

```js
[
   {
      "message":"[Syntax Error] line 0, col 103: Error: Expected '.' or '(', got 'weight'",
      "class":"Doctrine\\ORM\\Query\\QueryException",
      "trace":[
         {
            "namespace":"",
            "short_class":"",
            "class":"",
            "type":"",
            "function":"",
            "file":"C:\\webserver\\symfony\\vendor\\doctrine\\orm\\lib\\Doctrine\\ORM\\Query\\QueryException.php",
            "line":44,
            "args":[

            ]
         },
         {
            "namespace":"Doctrine\\ORM\\Query",
            "short_class":"QueryException",
            "class":"Doctrine\\ORM\\Query\\QueryException",
            "type":"::",
            "function":"syntaxError",
            // ...
```

Comment: Did you found solution for your problem?
I`m looking for a way to write DQL replace function

Comment: No,but I've decided to use $this->_em->createNativeQuery($sql, $rsm);  + as a simple condition. " AND cast(replace(weight,',','.') as float) >= :weight_from";

Comment: In case that you prefer to use DQL I already find a solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21534920/doctrine-squery-ignoring-spaces

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue and I suppose that you just should add a prefix to your table field "weight" (e.g. "a."):

```
$result->andWhere("replace(a.weight,X,C) <= :weight_from")
   ->setParameter('weight_from',$data['weight_from']);
```