# Doctrine query - ignoring spaces

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I`m looking for a way to create a doctrine query with ignoring spaces.
I try with replace but I receive all the time

> Expected known function, got 'replace'

My query look like:

```
        $query = $em->createQueryBuilder();

        $query->select('c')
                ->from('ACME\UserBudnle\Entity\User', 'c')
                ->where('replace(c.username," ","")'.' LIKE :searchName')
                ->setParameter('searchName', '%@' . $searchName. '%')
                ->orderBy('c.username', 'asc');
```

Comment: I don`t think that it`s duplicated because I`m looking for solution how to create query which will ignore spaces and will receive answer. For example: I have user: John Smith. If my :searchName= JohnSm. The query will return John Smith.

Comment: it Is duplicate, `DQL != MYSQL`, REPLACE function does not exist in DQL. Use the link provided above how to register custom functions.

Comment: If somebody help me to write a replace DQL function I will be very thankful

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ok I write a replace DQL Function.

```
<?php

namespace Acme\UserBundle\DQL;

use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer; 
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\FunctionNode; 


/**
 * "REPLACE" "(" StringPrimary "," StringSecondary "," StringThird ")"
 */
class replaceFunction extends FunctionNode{

    public $stringFirst; 
    public $stringSecond; 
    public $stringThird; 


    public function getSql(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker $sqlWalker) {
        return  'replace('.$this->stringFirst->dispatch($sqlWalker) .','
                . $this->stringSecond->dispatch($sqlWalker) . ',' 
                .$this->stringThird->dispatch($sqlWalker) . ')';
    }

    public function parse(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser $parser) {

        $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER);
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS);
        $this->stringFirst = $parser->StringPrimary();
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_COMMA);
        $this->stringSecond = $parser->StringPrimary();
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_COMMA);
        $this->stringThird = $parser->StringPrimary();
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS);
    }

}
```

Next in app/config.yml I add:

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        auto_mapping: true
        dql:
            string_functions:
                replace: Acme\UserBundle\DQL\replaceFunction
```

And finally I create a DQL query in my Controller:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $query = $em->createQueryBuilder();

    $query->select('u')
            ->from('Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User', 'u')

            ->where("replace(u.username,' ','') LIKE replace(:username,' ','') ")
            ->setParameter('username', '%' . $usernameForm . '%')
            ->orderBy('u.username', 'asc');


    $result = $query->getQuery()->getResult();
```

The most funny thing is that "quotes" are very important. It means that you can see that in select, from, setParameter and orderBy I use '' but in where I use "" and space ''. The opposite is not working. I don`t know why.

Comment: Thanks mate. Works great on Sf 4.4 with little changes.