# Use advanced select in doctrine2/ symfony2

Tags: php, regex, symfony, doctrine-orm, advanced-custom-fields

I needed to find a way to get number of $text occurances in my responsibilities field which is text type.

I tried to put query like this:

```
select("cv.id, (CHAR_LENGTH(cve.responsibilities)
-
CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(LOWER(cve.responsibilities),LOWER(" . $text. "),'')))/CHAR_LENGTH(" . $text . ") AS count")
```

in to my queryBuilder in symfony2.

I know that this kind of querys are far away from optimal, but im pushed to do it this way.
I added a replace and regexp function in to my functionNode but the main problem is with selecting a field. Here is what i'v tried(i split code for extra variables for your clarity):

```
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('a');
        $expr = $qb->select()->expr();

        $diff1 = $expr->length("b.description");
        $diff2 = $expr->length("replace( " . $expr->lower('b.description') . ", " . $expr->lower(':text') .", '')");

        $counter = $expr->diff($diff1, $diff2);
        $denominator = $expr->length(':text');

        $qb->select('a.id,' . $expr->quot(':counter', ':denominator') . 'as count')
            ->join('a.additional', 'b')
            ->where('REGEXP ("[[:<:]]' . $text . '[[:>:]]", b.description)')
            ->andWhere('a.id IN (:Ids)')
            ->setParameters([
                'text' => $text,
                'counter' => $counter,
                'denominator' => $denominator,
                'Ids' => $Ids
            ]);
```

Ok so it works with :

```
$qb->select('a.id id,' . $expr->quot($counter, $denominator . ' field'))
            ->join('a.additional', 'b')
            ->where("regexp('[[:<:]]" . $text . "[[:>:]]', b.description) != false")
            ->andWhere('a.id IN (:Ids)')
            ->setParameter('text', $text );
        if(!empty($Ids)){
            $qb->andWhere('a.id IN (:Ids)')
                ->setParameter('Ids', $Ids);
        }
```

Comment: Explain what it does wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so i couldn't use

```
 $qb->select('a.id,' . $expr->quot(':counter', ':denominator') . 'as count')
```

instead i've changed name from 'count' to 'field' nad removed 'as'

```
$qb->select('a.id id,' . $expr->quot($counter, $denominator . ' field'))
```

i used: [replace class](https://gist.github.com/K-Phoen/6108436) and [regexp](http://www.danieledangeli.com/enabling-mysql-regexp-in-symfony2/)

And it works. PROBLEM SOLVED

Answer (score 0):

Its always better using SQL query for large data than using DQL try something like this :

```
LENGTH( cve.responsibilities) - LENGTH(REPLACE(cve.responsibilities, '. $text.', '')) AS counts
```

this should give you the count or occurences in the field responsibilities.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this in your repository class, call and get result i have tested it in my side

```
public function getTested()
    {   
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('cve')
            ->select("cve.id, (LENGTH(cve.responsibilities) - LENGTH(REPLACE(cve.responsibilities, '". $text ."','')))/LENGTH('". $text ."')")
            ->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
    }
```

Here REPLACE function do following link
[Doctrine query - ignoring spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21534920/doctrine-query-ignoring-spaces/21652988#21652988)

Comment: allready solved, thx for help, used similar code for replace functionNode